# SQL left outer join's unexpected output

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables,
`rolls` and `rollsout`.  I would like to perform a left outer join .

#### rolls

```
          |type|height|weight|Rate|
          -------------------------
          |RP  |2ft   | 200  | 100|
          |RP  |2ft   | 200  | 100|
          |RP  |2ft   | 200  | 100|
          |LD  |2ft   | 100  | 130|
```

#### rollsout

```
          |type|height|weight|Rate|
          -------------------------
          |RP  |2ft   | 200  | 100|
          |RP  |2ft   | 200  | 100|
```

Expected output after SUMing, JOINing and GROUPings ==>

```
          |type|height|SUM(rolls.weight)|SUM(rollsout.weight)|
          ----------------------------------------------------
          |RP  |2ft   | 600             | 400                |
          |LD  |2ft   | 100             | NILL               |
```

---

My code:

```
 SELECT rolls.hight,rolls.type,SUM(rolls.weight),SUM(rollsout.weight)
 FROM rolls 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN rollsout 
 ON rolls.hight = rollsout.hight AND rolls.type= rollsout.type 
 GROUP BY rolls.hight,rolls.type
```

But the O/P for the above code is

```
          |type|height|SUM(rolls.weight)|SUM(rollsout.weight)|
          ----------------------------------------------------
          |RP  |2ft   | 1200            | 1200               |
          |LD  |2ft   | 100             | NILL               |
```

I don't know where I am going wrong — can you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. That's the behaviour of JOINs

It is number of rows on the left X number of rows on the right and in your case, it 3 x 2 = 6. And `6 x 200 = 1200`

try this

```
Select rolls.height,rolls.type, SUM(rolls.weight) as W, rollsout.Ww
 FROM rolls 
 LEFT JOIN
       (Select height,type, SUM(weight) as Ww 
         From rollsout GROUP BY height, type
       ) as rollsout
ON rolls.height = rollsout.height AND 
rolls.type= rollsout.type 
GROUP BY rolls.height,rolls.type
```

### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d15cc/19)

I know this won't work in SQL Server, but it worked for MySQL

Answer (score 0):

It's summing all of Rolls for each row in Rollsout with type RP.  You need to get the distinct rows from rollsout:

```
SELECT rolls.hight,rolls.type,SUM(rolls.weight),SUM(R2.weight)
 FROM rolls 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM rollsout) AS R2 ON  
 ON rolls.hight = R2.hight AND rolls.type= R2.type 
 GROUP BY rolls.hight,rolls.type
```

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply. but i am getting the following error when i use ur code: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON rolls.hight = R2.hight AND rolls.type= R2.type GROUP BY rolls.hight,rolls.ty' at line 1

Comment: Yeah, sorry I missed that you were using mysql. My head's in sql server land. If I get a chance I'll lookup the equivalent mysql syntax.