# TSQL - LEFT OUTER JOIN unexpected results

Tags: t-sql, left-join

I know that LEFT OUTER JOIN means "give me everything in the left-hand table, and return the details on matches in the right-hand table, and NULL values where there are no matches", so given the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Items(
    WarehouseNumber varchar(2),
    ItemNumber varchar(8),
    ItemDescription varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Items(WarehouseNumber, ItemNumber, ItemDescription) VALUES('01', '12345', 'Widget')
INSERT INTO #Items(WarehouseNumber, ItemNumber, ItemDescription) VALUES('02', '12345', 'Widget')
INSERT INTO #Items(WarehouseNumber, ItemNumber, ItemDescription) VALUES('07', '12345', 'Widget')

CREATE TABLE #InvoiceHdr(
    InvoiceNumber varchar(8),
    WarehouseNumber varchar(2),
    DateOrdered datetime,
    DateInvoiced datetime
)

INSERT INTO #InvoiceHdr(InvoiceNumber, WarehouseNumber, DateOrdered, DateInvoiced) VALUES('1', '01', '20190101', '20190102')
INSERT INTO #InvoiceHdr(InvoiceNumber, WarehouseNumber, DateOrdered, DateInvoiced) VALUES('2', '07', '20190102', '20190103')
INSERT INTO #InvoiceHdr(InvoiceNumber, WarehouseNumber, DateOrdered, DateInvoiced) VALUES('3', '02', '20190201', '20190202')
INSERT INTO #InvoiceHdr(InvoiceNumber, WarehouseNumber, DateOrdered, DateInvoiced) VALUES('4', '07', '20190216', '20190217')
INSERT INTO #InvoiceHdr(InvoiceNumber, WarehouseNumber, DateOrdered, DateInvoiced) VALUES('5', '07', '20190221', '20190222')

CREATE TABLE #InvoiceDtl(
    InvoiceNumber varchar(8),
    InvoiceLineItem int,
    ItemNumber varchar(8),
    QtyOrdered int,
    QtyShipped int
)

INSERT INTO #InvoiceDtl(InvoiceNumber, InvoiceLineItem, ItemNumber, QtyOrdered, QtyShipped) VALUES('1', 1, '12345', 4, 4)
INSERT INTO #InvoiceDtl(InvoiceNumber, InvoiceLineItem, ItemNumber, QtyOrdered, QtyShipped) VALUES('2', 1, '12345', 33, 30)
INSERT INTO #InvoiceDtl(InvoiceNumber, InvoiceLineItem, ItemNumber, QtyOrdered, QtyShipped) VALUES('3', 1, '12345', 5, 5)
INSERT INTO #InvoiceDtl(InvoiceNumber, InvoiceLineItem, ItemNumber, QtyOrdered, QtyShipped) VALUES('4', 1, '12345', 7, 7)
INSERT INTO #InvoiceDtl(InvoiceNumber, InvoiceLineItem, ItemNumber, QtyOrdered, QtyShipped) VALUES('5', 1, '12345', 8, 8

SELECT I.ItemNumber,
        I.WarehouseNumber,
        SUM(Details.Qty) 'Qty'
FROM #Items I
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT IH.DateInvoiced,
                                IH.WarehouseNumber,
                                ID.ItemNumber,
                                SUM(ID.QtyOrdered) 'Qty'
                        FROM #InvoiceHdr IH
                            INNER JOIN #InvoiceDtl ID ON IH.InvoiceNumber = ID.InvoiceNumber
                        GROUP BY IH.DateInvoiced,
                                    ID.ItemNumber,
                                    IH.WarehouseNumber) Details ON I.ItemNumber = Details.ItemNumber
                                        AND I.WarehouseNumber = Details.WarehouseNumber
WHERE Details.DateInvoiced >= '20190101'
    AND Details.DateInvoiced < '20190108'
GROUP BY I.ItemNumber,
            I.WarehouseNumber
```

.....I receive the following results:

```
ItemNumber | WarehouseNumber | Qty
==================================
12345      | 01              | 4
12345      | 07              | 33
```

when I am expecting:

```
ItemNumber | WarehouseNumber | Qty
==================================
12345      | 01              | 4
12345      | 02              | NULL
12345      | 07              | 33
```

I have looked at [this question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096025/sql-left-outer-joins-unexpected-output), but the accepted solution  specifically states "I know this won't work in SQL Server, but it worked for MySQL".  I am *wanting* this to work in SQL Server (2005, if possible, 2016 if not)

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. A where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join". You have that. PS This is an easily found faq. Before considering posting please always google many clear, precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names. If you ask, use one as title.

Comment: Your where clause is testing the right-hand side of the join. When `DateInvoiced` is `NULL`, the where clause discards the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `WHERE` to an `AND` and you should be good. Putting your date condition in the `WHERE` clause excludes it from the result set. Putting it in the join excludes it from the joined table, resulting in the NULL value in your result set.

```
SELECT  I.ItemNumber
        , I.WarehouseNumber
        , SUM(Details.Qty) 'Qty'
FROM    #Items I
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  IH.DateInvoiced
                    , IH.WarehouseNumber
                    , ID.ItemNumber
                    , SUM(ID.QtyOrdered) 'Qty'
            FROM    #InvoiceHdr IH
                    INNER JOIN #InvoiceDtl ID ON IH.InvoiceNumber = ID.InvoiceNumber
            GROUP BY IH.DateInvoiced, ID.ItemNumber, IH.WarehouseNumber
        ) Details ON 
            I.ItemNumber = Details.ItemNumber
            AND I.WarehouseNumber = Details.WarehouseNumber
/*WHERE*/   AND Details.DateInvoiced >= '20190101'
            AND Details.DateInvoiced < '20190108'
GROUP BY I.ItemNumber, I.WarehouseNumber
```